# Recursion Extracting Digits Using a Base

Tags: python, recursion

Homework help needed here. 
Im really struggling to get my head around recursion and the way it works.

The problem is, write a recursive function dec2base(n,b) that returns the list of base b digits in the positive integer n

exmaple:

```
dec2base(120, 10) => [1,2,0] (1*10*2 + 2/10**1 + 0*10**0)
```

I understand there should be a stop case but i cant think of what it might be.

So at the moment, all my code looks like is:

```
def dec2base(n, b):
    if
```

And that's it. Any guidance would be amazing. Thankyou!

EDIT: tired a code for somehting like this:

```
def dec2base(n, b):
    if n < 10:
        return [n]
    else:
        return getdigits(n/b) + [n%b]
```

but that doesnt get me anwyehre...

Comment: What would you do if the number was 10? What would you do if the number was 9? What is the difference between these numbers? That might help you figure out the base case.

Comment: if the number was 10, its already at the base? so base case should just return n if n == 10?

Comment: No, you want the list of digits. 10 is two digits. So you need to go one step further at 10. At 9 you are done.

Comment: any chance you can look at the code i just editted in? is that close?

Comment: A hint: it's probably going to be easiest to generate the digits from right to left.

Comment: That is looking closer. Just fix your syntax so it actually runs. Some arguments and function names are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To understand recursion, one has to first understand recursion.
You stated the stop case by yourself, it's of course when it's reached `base**0`

Edit: @your Edit: you almost got it, do not give up. how many arguments does dec2base take? think!

Answer (score 0):

The key element to this task is understanding (or devising) 
[Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).
We can write numbers in your way:

1234 = 1*10<sup>3</sup> + 2*10<sup>2</sup> + 3*10<sup>1</sup> + 4*10<sup>0</sup>

But after thinking a bit we come up with this representation:

1234 = 123*10 + 4 = (12*10 + 3)*10 + 4 = ((1*10 + 2)*10 + 3)*10 + 4

I hope you can see recursion more clearly. In each step, check if number can be divided mod 10. If so, remainder is next digit and quotient can be worked on recursively.

Answer (score -1):

```
def dec2base(n,b):
    if n < b:
        return [n]
    else:
        return dec2base(n//b, b) + [n%b]
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Code only answers often become downvoted and possibly removed. See [answer].